# Que serían "el hablante y el oyente" en la frase "Cuando ellos, el hablante y el oyente, conocen el tema"

Tags: gramática

En la frase "Cuando ellos, el hablante y el oyente, conocen el tema", supongo que "ellos" es el sujeto y "el tema" es el objeto directo. Entonces que serían "el hablante y el oyente"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El sujeto no es *ellos*, sino la frase completa *ellos, el hablante y el oyente*. El pronombre *ellos* por sí solo forma el núcleo del sujeto; el resto es una [aposición](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aposici%C3%B3n) que aclara o especifica al núcleo, como en los ejemplos:

- *Todos, grandes y pequeños, entendieron lo que quería decir.*
- *Mi hermana, la que trabaja en el hospital, está embarazada.*
- *El presidente del directorio, el Sr. González, ha decidido renunciar.*